# Finiteness of Radon Measure of Compact Sets

Tags: measure-theory

I came across the following definition for a particular Radon measure:

Let $E$ be a locally compact space, and define the measure $\epsilon_x(A) = 1$ if $x \in A$, $0$ otherwise for all $A$ in the Borel sigma field generated by $E$. Let $\{x_i, i \geq 1\}$ be a countable collection of not necessarily distinct elements of $E$. Then the following measure, $m$, is Radon: $$ m(A) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \epsilon_{x_i}(A)$$ and is finite for all compact sets $A$ in the Borel sigma field generated by $E$. Obviously, I'm missing something because my thinking is that if I take the $x_i$ to all be non-distinct elements, and make them all the same element. Then, surely, $m(\{x_1\}) = \infty$ is not finite because all the $x_i$ would be in the set $\{x_1\}$ since $x_i = x_1$ for all $i \geq 1$, and $\{x_1\}$ is compact. What am I missing?

Comment: My guess would be that they missed some factors that render this finite (e.g. $2^{-i} \epsilon_{x_i}$ instead of $\epsilon_{x_i}$). Otherwise you might run into troubles even if all the elements are distinct. For example $E=[0;1]$, $x_i=1/i$ does not yield a Radon measure (in that case $m([0;1])$ would need to be finite).

Comment: Right, that was my impression as well. Thanks for your clarification